# android studio: dependencies error

Tags: android, dependencies

I am new in android studio. I tried to add implementation `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'` to my project and I got an error.

this is my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can you help me solve this? I have been stuck for a week. :(

Comment: What's the error? Try changing the `15.0.1` to `16.0.1`, i.e `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1`
and `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1`

Comment: the error is "failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms.play-services;15.0.1"... okay will try that.. thanks sir

Comment: sir, ive tried that. still got the same error.. do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you need all the play services or any specific of them: Just try using `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'` and remove the other one. Just use the specific ones that you need. Are you following https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup ?